# Problems with accessing values in associate arrays / objects

Tags: autohotkey

I have a file that is fundamentally the following:

```
global t = {"0x00FF14": 123} 

manageModifierStates(color) {
    test := t[color]
    Tooltip, %test% | %color%, 11, 11
}

~\::
    PixelGetColor, pixelColor, 10, 10, RGB
    manageModifierStates(pixelColor)
Return
```

The result of me pressing the \ key is that I get a tooltip where there is nothing on the left side of the pipe, but on the right side **0x00FF14** is displayed. What am I doing wrong with the accessing of the objects property? I want/expect the tooltip to result in **123 | 0x00FF14**

Thank you for any insight you can give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you the details of the technical answer, but it's a problem of data types (numbers vs strings).

For some reason the declaration of objects sometimes is too rigid compared to the flexibility that variables exhibit on the rest of ahk.

Now getting into your issue, the syntax 0x... doesn't need quotes in ahk. It's recognized as a number, an hexadecimal number to be exact. So you are safe removing the quotes that you put around it. Moreover is a way to get your issue fixed.

The other way is that after your declaration you simply do this workaround:

```
global t = {"0x00FF14": 123}
for k,v in t
    t[k] := v
```